# I did factory reset without taking backup of messages. can i recover those messages?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, factory-reset, data-recovery, htc-explorer

I have did factory reset my phone with out taking backup of messages... its all important messages.. can i recover those messages back. if so, please guide me.

Phone : HTC Explorer

Comment: A factory reset wipes android settings, databases used by apps, including Messaging. In short, you're out of luck. :(

Comment: What messages? SMS? Email? Kik? WhatsApp? Skype?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about your SMS/MMS messages, then there's practically no way to get them back.